# Input validation through banner and textbox color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have these textbox and selectbox that I need to validate if there is an input or none upon button click. I needed the blank textbox to be red in color as well as if in my select dropdown. And upon entering an input, how can the red color mark disappear? Please help

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#add').on('click', function() {
    bootstrap_alert('PLEASE FILL IN VALUES');
  });
  bootstrap_alert = function(message) {
    var uname = $("#uname").val();
    var age = $("#age").val();
    var sex = $("#sex").val();

    if (uname.length == 0 || age.length == 0 || sex.index == 0) {
      $('#alert_placeholder').html('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><span>' + message + '</span></div>')
      $("#uname").css({
        "background-color": "#ff3300"
      });
      $("#age").css({
        "background-color": "#ff3300"
      });
      $("#sex").css({
        "background-color": "#ff3300"
      });
    } else {
      $('#alert_placeholder').html('');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>

<div id="alert_placeholder"></div>
Name: <input type="text" id="uname" /> Age: <input type="text" id="age" /> Sex:
<select id="sex" name="sex" />
<option value="" selected="selected"> Please Select </option>
<option value="Male"> Male </option>
<option value="Female"> Female </option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add">
```

Comment: set the background-color to empty string .

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo using jquery [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#uname, #age, #sex").on('input', function() {
    let $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val().trim()) {
      $(this).removeClass('input-invalid');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('input-invalid');
    }
  });

  $('#add').on('click', function() {
    bootstrap_alert('PLEASE FILL IN VALUES');
  });
  bootstrap_alert = function(message) {
    var uname = $("#uname").val();
    var age = $("#age").val();
    var sex = $("#sex").val();

    if (uname.length == 0 || age.length == 0 || sex.length == 0) {
      $('#alert_placeholder').html('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><span>' + message + '</span></div>')

      if (uname.length == 0) $("#uname").addClass('input-invalid');
      if (age.length == 0) $("#age").addClass('input-invalid');
      if (sex.length == 0) $("#sex").addClass('input-invalid');
    } else {
      $('#alert_placeholder').html('');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.input-invalid {
  background-color: #f2dede;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>

<div id="alert_placeholder"></div>
Name: <input type="text" id="uname" /> Age: <input type="text" id="age" /> Sex:
<select id="sex" name="sex" />
<option value="" selected="selected"> Please Select </option>
<option value="Male"> Male </option>
<option value="Female"> Female </option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add">
```

Comment: When I input a value before clicking the button, the textbox/select list should not turn into red

Comment: @BlueMinnie cant get u

Comment: if there is already a value in the textbox, it should not turn into red upn clicking button

Comment: Last question, what if there is an input after clicking the button then the user decides to erase it, is there a way that it can turn to red again?

Comment: @BlueMinnie You are not mentioned that in question anyhow check the update

Answer (score 0):

Change the color of the input to white on keyup event and the color of the select box on click

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#uname').keyup(function(){
$('#uname').css({
        "background-color": "white"
      });
})
$('#age').keyup(function(){
$('#age').css({
        "background-color": "white"
      });
})
$('#sex').click(function(){
$('#sex').css({
        "background-color": "white"
      });
})

  $('#add').on('click', function() {
    bootstrap_alert('PLEASE FILL IN VALUES');
  });
  bootstrap_alert = function(message) {
    var uname = $("#uname").val();
    var age = $("#age").val();
    var sex = $("#sex").val();

    if (uname == '')
    {
     $('#alert_placeholder').html('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><span>' + message + '</span></div>')
     $("#uname").css({
        "background-color": "#ff3300"
      });
      
    }
    else {
      $('#alert_placeholder').html('');
    }
    if( age=='')
    {
     $('#alert_placeholder').html('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><span>' + message + '</span></div>')
      $("#age").css({
        "background-color": "#ff3300"
      });
    }
    else {
      $('#alert_placeholder').html('');
    }
    if(sex.index==0){
      $('#alert_placeholder').html('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><span>' + message + '</span></div>')
     
      $("#sex").css({
        "background-color": "#ff3300"
      });
    } else {
      $('#alert_placeholder').html('');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>

<div id="alert_placeholder"></div>
Name: <input type="text" id="uname" /> Age: <input type="text" id="age" /> Sex:
<select id="sex" name="sex" />
<option value="" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
<option value="Male"> Male </option>
<option value="Female"> Female </option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add">
```

Comment: Textbox should not turn into red if there is an input